# Fragmentation-resistant Microcontroller Heap Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, heap-memory, microcontroller

I am looking to implement a heap allocation algorithm in C for a memory-constrained microcontroller.  I have narrowed my search down to 2 options I'm aware of, however I am very open to suggestions, and I am looking for advice or comments from anyone with experience in this.

**My Requirements:**

-Speed definitely counts, but is a secondary concern.

-Timing determinism is not important - any part of the code requiring deterministic worst-case timing has its own allocation method.

-The MAIN requirement is fragmentation immunity.  The device is running a lua script engine, which will require a range of allocation sizes (heavy on the 32 byte blocks). The main requirement is for this device to run for a long time without churning its heap into an unusable state.

**Also Note:**

-For reference, we are talking about a Cortex-M and PIC32 parts, with memory ranging from 128K and 16MB or memory (with a focus on the lower end).

-I don't want to use the compiler's heap because 1) I want consistent performance across all compilers and 2) their implementations are generally very simple and are the same or worse for fragmentation.

-double indirect options are out because of the huge Lua code base that I don't want to fundamtnetally change and revalidate.

**My Favored Approaches Thus Far:**

1) Have a binary buddy allocator, and sacrifice memory usage efficiency (rounding up to a power of 2 size).
-this would (as I understand) require a binary tree for each order/bin to store free nodes sorted by memory address for fast buddy-block lookup for rechaining.

2) Have two binary trees for free blocks, one sorted by size and one sorted by memory address. (all binary tree links are stored in the block itself)
-allocation would be best-fit using a lookup on the table by size, and then remove that block from the other tree by address
-deallocation would lookup adjacent blocks by address for rechaining

-Both algorithms would also require storing an allocation size before the start of the allocated block, and have blocks go out as a power of 2 minus 4 (or 8 depending on alignment).  (Unless they store a binary tree elsewhere to track allocations sorted by memory address, which I don't consider a good option)

-Both algorithms require height-balanced binary tree code.

-Algorithm 2 does not have the requirement of wasting memory by rounding up to a power of two.

-In either case, I will probably have a fixed bank of 32-byte blocks allocated by nested bit fields to off-load blocks this size or smaller, which would be immune to external fragmentation.

**My Questions:**

-Is there any reason why approach 1 would be more immune to fragmentation than approach 2?

-Are there any alternatives that I am missing that might fit the requirements?

Comment: The buddy system doesn't have to use a binary tree to find the possible buddy of a block when freeing it. You can work out the address of a buddy from the address of the original block. Then you check a bit to see if that buddy is free or used. You can put that bit in the start of the area - so you wouldn't actually get 32 bytes, but perhaps 31 usable bytes. You can change this by using a separate bitmap for free/used. Knuth describes a version that uses tag bits for free/used

Comment: Yah, I just thought of that.  I think 2GB block size is probably good enough :)  What I also think would work to get rid of the binary tree for free nodes would be to store each bin/order's free nodes in a double-linked circular list, and just use the buddy's pointer to chain up the next and previous nodes (and advance the head ptr by one node if it was pointing to the node being removed).  This way there's no searching involved at all to find and remove a free buddy.  Thus, no binary tree implementation.  Thoughts?

Comment: do you really need to allocate?  embedded systems like these typically do not allocate but use fixed size structures (except of course stack, which you have to be careful about).  adds too much risk to something that is supposed to be rock solid.

Comment: @dwelch Non-stack allocation is actually very common on a micro.  Most embedded RTOS's use some type of heap-like allocator to avoid having to hard code in sizes of absolutely everything.  It's the repeated allocation/deallocation of blocks whose size that can't be predicted that's an issue.  As I mentioned, I would like to run a lua interpreter on the system, which is predominantly designed for a larger platform, and relies entirely on a heap allocator that you have to provide.  The system is a high-reliability system, but lua will be used for non-critical sub-systems.

Answer (score 1):

If block sizes are not rounded up to powers of two or some equivalent(*), certain sequences of allocation and deallocation will generate an essentially-unbounded amount of fragmentation even if the number of non-permanent small objects that exist at any given time is limited.  A binary-buddy allocator will, of course, avoid that particular issue.  Otherwise, if one is using a limited number of nicely-related object sizes but not using a "binary buddy" system, one may still have to use some judgment in deciding where to allocate new blocks.

Another approach to consider is having different allocation methods for things that are expected to be permanent, temporary, or semi-persistent.  Fragmentation often causes the most trouble when temporary and permanent things get interleaved on the heap.  Avoiding such interleaving may minimize fragmentation.

Finally, I know you don't really want to use double-indirect pointers, but allowing object relocation can greatly reduce fragmentation-related issues.  Many Microsoft-derived microcomputer BASICs used a garbage-collected string heap; Microsoft's garbage collector was really horrible, but its string-heap approach can be used with a good one.

Comment: Very helpful indeed!  By powers of two or equivalent, are you talking about fibonacci buddies, etc?  Can you give me a simple example of a pattern that would demonstrate the strength of a binary/other buddy system? I can't seem to come up with one myself...

Comment: Also, as for double indirect, this would involve completely rewriting the lua engine to support double indirect allocation...  maybe there's a gem there waiting to be written.  Either way, that would be a scary amount of validation.  As for the OS, it does use a form of double-indirect in the handles table, and pools of identically size buffers for stream buffering, so it's really only the lua I'm concerned about.  How does one simulate/test for/quantify memory space fragmentation?

Comment: One advantage of power of two buddies is that some users of memory happen to require power of two block sizes - you mentioned that Lua wanted 32-byte blocks, and some embedded systems might want to do FFTs with power of two block sizes. If you can actually use all of a power of two buddy block size (and not have to devote a bit to free/used) then this is a pretty good fit - which is why I wrote a demo of a buddy system with external free/used bitmap, just to show that it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can pick up a (never used for real) Buddy system allocator at http://www.mcdowella.demon.co.uk/buddy.html, with my blessing for any purpose you like. But I don't think you have a problem that is easily solved just by plugging in a memory allocator. The long-running high integrity systems I am familiar with have predictable resource usage, described in 30+ page documents for each resource (mostly cpu and I/O bus bandwidth - memory is easy because they tend to allocate the same amount at startup every time and then never again).

In your case none of the usual tricks - static allocation, free lists, allocation on the stack, can be shown to work because - at least as described to us - you have a Lua interpreted hovering in the background ready to do who knows what at run time - what if it just gets into a loop allocating memory until it runs out?

Could you separate the memory use into two sections - traditional code allocating almost all of what it needs on startup, and never again, and expendable code (e.g. Lua) allowed to allocate whatever it needs when it needs it, from whatever is left over after static allocation? Could you then trigger a restart or some sort of cleanup of the expendable code if it manages to use all of its area of memory, or fragments it, without bothering the traditional code?

Comment: That's a very good point: to design in a scheduled restart of the Lua engine, which I'm beginning to think is unavoidable.  And yes, the lua allocation is completely sandboxed from other memory allocation.  I can ensure fragmentation-immunity for all other dynamic memory allocation.  I just can't guarantee that even known-good lua code with plenty of spare heap won't slowly churn itself to death.  I supposed I could on-the-fly serialize and migrate the entire contents of the lua environment from one lua engine to another, but that's getting kind of crazy.